# PHP-AJAX: How to pass URL variable through Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have set an Ajax call for Pagination. I need to pass one more vaiable which is stored in the URL

**URL**

```
http://thisite.com/pagetitl/?id=12  **// where 'id=' is a variable I want to pass.**
```

**Ajax Call**

```
function page(page) {
    var dataString = '&page=' + page; // pagination with ajax
    pag.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "cmn_pg.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function (ccc) {
            pag("#search_results").html(ccc);
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried to GET it in PHP file `$id=$_GET[id]`, but wont work.

I ask how to pass it with AJAX because I'm quite new to AJAX.

Comment: Try if(isset($_GET['id'])) { $id=$_GET['id']; }

Comment: If you want to use $_GET then you have to pass it along with the url,
that is after 'cmn_pg.php?page='+page
Also use $_GET['page']

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are building your query string manually then:

```
dataString = 'page=' + encodeURIComponent(page);
```

but you are using jQuery, so don't build it manually:

```
url: "cmn_pg.php",
data: {
    "page": page
},
success: function (ccc) {
```

(You also need to use the right name for it in PHP: `<?php $id = $_GET['page'] ?>`)

Comment: +1 for both covering his errors in his question code *and* answering the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass via url like this

```
pag.ajax
({
type: "GET",
url: "cmn_pg.php?page="+page,
success: function(ccc)
  {
    pag("#search_results").html(ccc);
  }
});
```

Or

```
pag.ajax
({
type: "post",
url: "cmn_pg.php",
data: {'data':dataString},//You can add as many datas seperated by comma to pass more values
success: function(ccc)
  {
    pag("#search_results").html(ccc);
  }
});
```

And in php

```
$dataString = $_POST['data'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function page(page) {
   var dataString = '&page=' + page; // pagination with ajax pag.ajax
   ({
     type: "GET",
     url: "cmn_pg.php",
     data: {
      page: page
     },
     success: function(ccc) {
       pag("#search_results").html(ccc);
     }
   });

if more data is there to pass add to data variable as given bellow :-
data : {page:page,data2:data2},
```

Answer (score 0):

You named the variable "page" and try to access it via "id" in PHP. You have to create the query string liek this:

```
var  dataString = '&id=' + page;
```

Alertnitavly you can use pass an object to the "data" parameter andjQUery does the transformationf for you. Sample:

```
 data: { id: page },
```

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
>   not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See
>   processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must
>   be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple
>   values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting
>   (described below).

Soruce: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
pag.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "cmn_pg.php",
    data: {
        page: page, // your page number
        id:12// your id to send
    },
    success: function (ccc) {
        pag("#search_results").html(ccc);
    }
});
```