# Get url variable from AJAX in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables, url

I've looked at a couple of related topics here on Stackoverflow such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19808344/2620873), but I can't seem to get this one correct – it could be something particular in my code, but I don't think that should be the case, thus I'm seeking your advice.

My goal is to pass `index.php?key=123testID` through the client.js script below to my update-check.php in order to long-poll the txt file with the corresponding name (in this example 123testID.txt). If there's an other way for update-checker to grab the variable, that is also acceptable.

**I currently have working functionality for long-polling the .txt data – I simply want to add the functionality to dynamically load the txt file with the same name as the URL variable.**
At the moment my code looks like this:

**client.js**

```
function getContent(timestamp)
{
    var queryString = {'timestamp' : timestamp};

    $.ajax(
        {
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'update-check.php',
        data: queryString,
        success: function(data){
            // put result data into "obj"
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            // put the data_from_file into #response
            $('#response').html(obj.data_from_file);
            // call the function again, this time with the timestamp we just got from server.php
            getContent(obj.timestamp);
            }
        }
    );
}

// initialize jQuery
$(function() {
    getContent();
});
```

**update-check.php**

```
<?php

// set php runtime to unlimited
set_time_limit(0);

// how can I load a variable insead of a static txt file?
$data_source_file = "stories/123testID.txt";

// main loop
while (true) {

// if ajax request has send a timestamp, then $last_ajax_call = timestamp, else $last_ajax_call = null
$last_ajax_call = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? (int)$_GET['timestamp'] : null;

clearstatcache();
// get timestamp of when file has been changed the last time
$last_change_in_data_file = filemtime($data_source_file);

if ($last_ajax_call == null || $last_change_in_data_file > $last_ajax_call) {

    $data = file_get_contents($data_source_file);

    $result = array(
        'data_from_file' => $data,
        'timestamp' => $last_change_in_data_file
    );

    // encode to JSON, render the result (for AJAX)
    $json = json_encode($result);
    echo $json;


    // leave this loop step
    break;
    } else {
    sleep( 1 );
    continue;
}}?>
```

Comment: How is this not working for you? And note that your `filemtime()` call will use cached results after the first loop iteration. If you need to check for file changes, use [clear_stat_cache()](http://php.net/clear_stat_cache) to force "fresh" results.

Comment: Don't you mean `getContent(new Date().getTime());`  or `var queryString = {'timestamp' : timestamp||""};`

Comment: @MarcB The main problem is that I dont understand how to "get the variable through" my client.js (if there's a more efficient yet basic way of doing this that would be interesting also).

Comment: you're basically doing everything right, as far as I can see. jquery will take your `data: queryString` and append it to the url, making your request be `update-check.php?timestamp=value_of_timestamp`.

Comment: Are you missing the datatype attribute of the ajax method?: dataType: 'json',

Comment: @MarcB But how would I go about and insert the variable into `$data_source_file`? Would I still do a `$data_source_file = $_GET['key'];`, because that doesn't work?

Comment: start debugging: `var_dump($_GET)`, see what the script's receiving. `console.log(timestamp)`, see what the value is in your JS code.

Comment: just add it all to your data field  `timestamp=value_of_timestamp&key=123testID`

Comment: Might be in well over my head here :P I'll take a look and see if I can get it working, are there any alternative methods of doing something like this though?

Comment: You can use a `post` Query instead of a `get` Query.

Comment: I basically want to achieve [same thing as this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808202/php-ajax-how-to-pass-url-variable-through-ajax), while maintaining my current functionality – something I cannot figure out how to do.

Comment: Looks like you're over thinking it. You should be able to do a simple PHP GET: `$_GET['timestamp']` and retrieve your variables you post from data querystring.

Comment: @TreyCopeland that simply results in an Uncaught SyntaxError. I really don't know what to do at this point, and as you say there's no doubt I'm overthinking it at this point.

Comment: In addition to console.log() and print_r() you can use Network (Net) tab in Element Inspector to check what exactly moves between browser and server.

Comment: @RauliRajande Thanks, seems like I can't get the variable from the URL into the AJAX, got any suggestions?